# auto rip CD with morituri (or launch custom script on CD insert)

Tags: cd, udev

How can I automaticaly start ripping my CD when I insert a CD. There used to be a `custom command` option in the settings where you could run a custom command on CD insert. The I could use a bash script to start the ripping.

But that option isn't there anymore and I can only use programs?

I'm trying some things with udev but I had little success

/etc/udev/rules.d/10-srX_change.rules

```
SUBSYSTEM=="block", KERNEL=="sr0", ENV{ID_CDROM_MEDIA_CD}=="1", RUN+="/home/user/morituri.sh"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a dialog in <kbd>Details</kbd> which will allow you to run an action on insert:
[image]

But it only allows you to select Applications. If Morituri is an application, it should work fine - just select it under <kbd>Other Applications....</kbd>

If it does not appear in the selection dialogue, you will have to create an Application launcher file for it. My solution to this would be to create a `.desktop` file for your script using:

```
sudo nano /usr/share/applications/morituriCD.desktop
```

with the following contents *(Copy ALL of it, and paste it with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>)*:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Morituri CD program
Icon=brasero
Exec=/home/USER/Morituri.sh
Terminal=false
Categories=AudioVideo;DiscBurning;
MimeType=application/x-cd-image;application/x-cdrdao-toc;application/x-cue;application/x-toc;audio/x-scpls;audio/x-ms-asx;audio/x-mp3-playlist;audio/x-mpegurl;application/x-brasero;x-content/audio-cdda;x-content/video-dvd;x-content/video-vcd;x-content/video-svcd;x-content/image-picturecd;
Keywords=morituri;disc;cdrom;dvd;burn;audio;video;
NoDisplay=false
```

Save with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
, and exit with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>

Make sure that `Exec=` is linked to the correct path, and that the linked executable works. Make sure with:

```
chmod +x /home/USER/morituri.sh
/home/USER/morituri.sh
```

You should then get this:
[image]

Hope this helps ;-)

Comment: Thanks, this looks like it. I'm going to try and let you know

Comment: It doesn't show up as program (also not in the unity dash). Any idea?

Comment: I think it only showed for me after a reboot - check in the [Main Menu](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/alacarte/)  dialog, under 'Sound & Video'. The problem I had was the `Exec` path being incorrect, so it did not create the launcher.

Comment: Perfect! it showed up after a reboot (yes I know it's a late answer but I don't reboot very often ;))